# CSS Gradients - Less Mixins

Tags: css, less

I was just wondering if it's possible to alter the color of the Less mixin gradient by applying something like lighten or darken to the CSS code?

Here is the Less Mixin:

```
.css-gradient(@from: #20416A, @to: #3D69A5) {
    background-color: @to;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@from),  to(@to));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
}
```

And in Less file I would like to do something like this:

```
#div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    .css-gradient (darken, 10%);
}
```

Don't know if this is possible or if there is another way I should do this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you would like to achieve with the darken function, maybe you could provide a sample less and corresponding css code. That would make things clearer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd do this like so:

```
.css-gradient(darken(#20416A,10%),darken(#3D69A5,10%))
```

Of course you could also do:

```
.css-gradient(@from: #20416A, @to: #3D69A5) {
    background-color: @to;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@from),  to(@to));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, @from, @to);
}
.css-gradient(darken,@amount: 10%, @from: #20416A, @to: #3D69A5){
    .css-gradient(darken(@from,@amount),darken(@to,@amount));
}
```

And then just call it:

```
.css-gradient(darken,10%);
```

or:

```
.css-gradient(#20416A, #3D69A5);
```

or:

```
.css-gradient(darken,5%,#00ff00,#ff0000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Less mixin:

```
.gradient(@dir: 0deg; @colors; @prefixes: webkit, moz, ms, o; @index: length(@prefixes)) when (@index > 0) {
    .gradient(@dir; @colors; @prefixes; (@index - 1));

    @prefix : extract(@prefixes, @index);
    @dir-old: 90 - (@dir);

    background-image: ~"-@{prefix}-linear-gradient(@{dir-old}, @{colors})";
    & when ( @index = length(@prefixes) ) {
        background-image: ~"linear-gradient(@{dir}, @{colors})";
    }
}
```

Using: .gradient(90deg, #FFAA64, #FFCD73);